# Visualisation for etc_security_lastlog

Tags: security, users, aix

I am looking for an easy way to visualise data from etc_security_lastlog for reviewing inactive user IDs. "Inactive" users would be determined based on their time_last_login being old enough. How do I do it?

```
lp:
time_last_unsuccessful_login = 1174162435
tty_last_unsuccessful_login = /dev/pts/7      
host_last_unsuccessful_login = 1x.xxx.xxx.x.x                                    
unsuccessful_login_count = 1         

smtsftp:
unsuccessful_login_count = 3         
time_last_login = 1382043613
tty_last_login = /dev/ssh-16842912
host_last_login = 1x.xxx.xxx.x.x.net.intra                       
time_last_unsuccessful_login = 1382083294
tty_last_unsuccessful_login = ssh
host_last_unsuccessful_login = 1x.xxx.xxx.x.x.net.intra

svcsinae:
unsuccessful_login_count = 0         

privil1:
unsuccessful_login_count = 0
time_last_login = 1567112152
tty_last_login = /dev/pts/1
host_last_login = 11x.xxx.xxx.x.x              
time_last_unsuccessful_login = 1507892677
tty_last_unsuccessful_login = ssh
host_last_unsuccessful_login = 1x.xxx.xxx.x.x
```

Comment: What are your criteria for "inactive users"?

Comment: based on last login date after a certain period of time, (time_last_login)

Comment: How long? And would you ignore unsuccessful login times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could approach this with a simple awk filter; just pass in the current timestamp and the cutoff that you're interested in. It will parse the input looking for usernames and their time_last_login values. If it finds a value that's older than the cutoff, it reports the corresponding user.

The example below uses a rough approximation of 1 year (31,536,000 seconds).

```
awk -v now=$(date +%s) -v cutoff=31536000 '
  /^[^-+@~ ][^:"#,=\\\/?` ]+:$/ { 
    user=$1
    sub(/:$/, "", user)
  }
  /time_last_login = [[:digit:]]+/ { 
    if (now - $3 > cutoff) print user " has not logged in within the cutoff"
  }
  ' /etc/security/lastlog
```

The regex I used in searching for the username comes from the [mkuser documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/m_commands/mkuser.html).  After capturing the username (line), I remove the trailing colon from the username.

Comment: this is very helpful!